# What is the rationale behind std::bind and std::thread always copying arguments?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

It's pretty well known that the default behaviour of std::bind and std::thread is that it will copy (or move) the arguments passed to it, and to use reference semantics we will have to use reference wrappers.

1. Does anyone know why this makes a good default behaviour? Esp. in C++11 with rvalue reference and perfect forwarding, it seems to me that it makes more sense to just perfectly forward the arguments.
2. std::make_shared though doesn't always copy/move but just perfectly forward the provided arguments. Why are there two seemingly different behaviour of forwarding arguments here? (std::thread and std::bind that always copy/move vs std::make_shared that don't)

Comment: If you bind a reference to a local, you'll be in trouble.

Comment: I won't be if the called function doesn't exist beyond the scope of the local. There are a lot of things in C++ that lets you blow your foot off. My question is more to the point that this behaviour seems to be less intuitive.

Comment: At some point my answer contained a "and that local goes out of scope", but apparently it got erased after editting :S

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`make_shared` forwards to a constructor that is being called *now*. If the constructor uses call by reference semantics, it will get the reference; if it does call by value, it will make a copy. No problem here either way.

`bind` creates a delayed call to a function that is called at some unknown points in the future, when the local context is potentially gone. If `bind` were using perfect forwarding, you would have to copy the arguments that are normally sent byreference and not known to be live at the time of the actual call, *store them somewhere, and manage that storage*. With the current semantics `bind` does it for you.

Answer (score 7):

For both `std::bind` and `std::thread`, the invocation of the function on the given arguments is deferred from the call site. In both cases, exactly when the function will be called is simply unknown.

To forward the parameters directly in such a case would require storing references. Which may mean storing references to *stack* objects. Which may not exist when the call is actually executed.

Oops.

Lambdas can do it because you're given the ability to decide, on a per-capture basis, whether you want to capture by reference or value. Using `std::ref`, you can bind a parameter by reference.

Comment: Makes sense. Voted up! Would accept if I were allowed to accept two answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The most probable reason is simply that C++ uses value semantics by default pretty much everywhere.  And using references could easily create issues concerning the lifetime of the referred to object.

Comment: But isn't it C++'s principle that the programmer knows what it wants best? In the case of dangling reference, the programmer should be careful that its function's parameters will be by value if it wants to, and when our function's parameter takes a reference, I'd expect things to be forwarded perfectly as reference for whatever risk. Just a thought.

Comment: No. The principle is that the programmer does not pay in performance for features he does not use. The "know what are you doing" thing is only means to achieve this end, not the end in and by itself.

Comment: C++ has a lot of principles:-).  One of the most fundamental ones is that it uses value semantics by default; you have to explicitly request a reference or a pointer for it to do otherwise.  (Of course, the standard library doesn't always follow this rule---iterators and predicates are always by value, but other things tend to vary.)

Answer (score 1):

std::bind creates a callable which is detached from the call site of `std::bind`, thus it makes much sense to capture all arguments by value by default.

The general use case is to be identical to passing a function pointer to a function without knowing where it might end up.

Lambdas give more flexibility for the programmer to decide whether the lambda will live beyond the scope arguments are captured from.

Comment: Is it the same case for std::thread? In the case of thread start function it's less likely that it will be written as lambda. And forcing to use lambda's closure to pass by reference there can seem weird? Lambdas doesn't seem to solve all problems caused by this here.. I think?

Answer (score 1):

I did in fact write a small utility that creates a delayed invocation functor (somewhat `std::bind`-like, but without the nested bind expressions/placeholders features). My main motivation was this case that I found counter-intuitive:

```
using pointer_type = std::unique_ptr<int>;
pointer_type source();
void sink(pointer_type p);

pointer_type p = source();

// Either not valid now or later when calling bound()
// auto bound = std::bind(sink, std::move(p));
auto bound = std::bind(
    [](pointer_type& p) { sink(std::move(p)); }
    , std::move(p) );
bound();
```

The reason for that adaptor (which moves its lvalue ref argument to `sink`) is that the call wrapper return by `std::bind` always forwards the bound arguments as lvalues. This wasn't a problem with e.g. `boost::bind` in C++03 since that lvalue would either bind to a reference argument of the underlying Callable object or to a value argument via a copy. Doesn't work here since `pointer_type` is move-only.

The insight that I got is that there really are two things to consider: how the bound arguments should be *stored*, and how they should be *restored* (i.e. passed to the Callable object). The control that `std::bind` grants you is as follows: arguments are either stored in a shallow (via the use of `std::ref`) or regular manner (using `std::decay` with perfect forward); they are always restored as lvalues (with cv-qualifiers inherited from the owning call wrapper). Except that you can bypass the latter with a small on-site adaptor lambda expression like I just did.

It's arguably a lot of control and a lot of expression for relatively little to learn. In comparison my utility has semantics like `bind(f, p)` (decay and store copy, restore as lvalue), `bind(f, ref(p))` (store shallowly, restore as lvalue), `bind(f, std::move(p))` (decay and store from move, restore as rvalue), `bind(f, emplace(p))` (decay and store from move, restore as lvalue). This feels like learning an EDSL.

Comment: It is a very interesting idea, could you point us to the implementation so we can explore it? Also, the resulting functor can logically be called only once? And what happened if we copy the resulting functor?

Comment: @authchir [Code here](https://bitbucket.org/mickk/annex/src/8166e2d92508/include/annex/make_invoke.hpp) (and things like `emplace` are from [here](https://bitbucket.org/mickk/annex/src/8166e2d92508/include/annex/val.hpp)). You're correct that it's only correct to call the functor once (further calls forward an empty `pointer_type`), and in addition to that the call wrapper is move-only. This all also applies to the equivalent `std::bind` usage.

Comment: Also [unit test](https://bitbucket.org/mickk/annex/src/8166e2d92508/unit/make_invoke.cpp) shows typical usage.