# c++: Building async with packaged_task

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, c++11, packaged-task

I am attempting to implement async with a packaged_task.  I am attempting this via a templated function, bsync.  bsync takes 2 arguments: a function,f, and a parameter-pack, args, and returns a future, fut.  The future is of the type returned by f(args...).  Ie - the return is future

I think I am almost there, but I am getting a type-conversion error.  Any help would be appreciated:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;


//Implement bsync as a templated function
//Template parameters are (i) Fn (the function to run), (ii) Args, a parameter pack of arguments to feed the function
//The function returns a future<Ret>, where Ret is the return-type of Fn(Args)
template<class Fn,class...Args>
auto bsync(Fn f, Args&&...args)->future<result_of<decltype(f)&(Args&&...)>>{

    //Determine return-type
    typedef result_of<decltype(f)&(Args&&...)>::type A;

    //Initialize a packaged_task
    packaged_task <A(Args&&...)>tsk(f);

    //Initialize a future
    future<A> fut = tsk.get_future();

    //Run the packaged task in a separate thread
    thread th(move(tsk),(args)...);

    //Join the thread
    th.join();

    return fut;
}

int plus_one(int x){
    cout << "Adding 1 to " << x << endl;
    return x++;
}

int main(){
    auto x = bsync(plus_one, 1);

    cout << "Press any key to continue:" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First glaring problem: `future<result_of<decltype(f)&(Args&&...)>>`. You mean `future<result_of<decltype(f)&(Args&&...)>::type>`? (Also, since you have `Fn`, I'm not sure why you are using `decltype(f)` at all...)

Answer (score 3):

Your trailing return type is incorrect. You have:

```
future<result_of<decltype(f)&(Args&&...)>>
```

That is a `future` with type `result_of<...>`. You need to actually *evaluate* the `result_of` metafunction to produce the actual result type. That is:

```
future<typename result_of<Fn(Args&&...)>::type>
       ^^^^^^^^^                        ^^^^^^
```

Once you fix that, you're missing a `typename` in your `typedef` for `A`.

Comment: Also, check if C++14 `result_of_t` is available from your compiler.

Comment: Almost there -

Taking a look at the main function.  I can successfully pass bsync an arg&&, but not an arg.

Eg:
This works:
int y=1;
auto x = bsync(plus_one,y);

This doesn't work:
auto x = bsync(plus_one,1);

I'm guessing my implementation is somewhere off in reference-hell - any ideas?

Comment: @ice_planet_hoth_boss I assume you mean the opposite. That's because `thread` stores a copy of it's arguments, if you want to pass references you'll have to wrap them in `reference_wrapper`. See [Wakely's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28975738/2069064) answer to a related question.