# C++: Removing elements from the using lambda function with 2 parameters

Tags: c++, lambda

I have the following predefined lambda function:

```
auto condition = ParseCondition(is);
auto predicate = [condition](const Date& date, const string& event) {
    return condition->Evaluate(date, event);
```

What it does:

1. It takes string stream input and parses it into condition.
2. Lambda function takes this condition and compares it with date and event and returns true/false based on some condition.

I want to create a function, which uses `predicate, to delete elements from my map object.

My map object is map `<Date,std::vector<std::string>> db;`

I came up with the following idea:

```
for(auto &item : db){
     auto& date = item.first;
     auto& events = item.second;
     auto to_remove = std::remove_if(events.begin(),events.end(), predicate);
     events.erase(to_remove,events.end());
}
```

But the problem here is `predicate`, which must take 2 parameters: `Date` and `event` and I don't know how would I put `Date` into `remove_if`. How should I do it?

Comment: Create yet another, local lambda that captures the date and the predicate references.

Comment: @CarySwoveland good point! I edited tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::bind_front` if you have c++20, and use `std::cref` to avoid copying `date`.

```
for(auto &item : db){
     auto& date = item.first;
     auto& events = item.second;
     auto to_remove = std::remove_if(events.begin(),events.end(), std::bind_front(predicate, std::cref(date));
     events.erase(to_remove,events.end());
}
```

If you don't have c++20, since you are using lambdas, you clearly have c++11, and you can use `std::bind`.

```
for(auto &item : db){
     using namespace std::placeholders;
     auto& date = item.first;
     auto& events = item.second;
     auto to_remove = std::remove_if(events.begin(),events.end(), std::bind(predicate, std::cref(date), _1);
     events.erase(to_remove,events.end());
}
```

Note that many people advise against using `std::bind` because the syntax is not that intuitive and there's basically nothing that it can do but a lambda cannot. For more complex situations a lambda is usually clearer. In simple cases where `std::bind_front` and `std::bind_back`(in C++23) applies, `bind`-based solutions still have the advantage of being less verbose without loss of clarity. Another major difference is that with `bind` functions the callable is stored in the bind object and care must be taken if copying the callable is expensive. On the other hand, a lambda solution encodes the operation in it's type and the callable does not need to be copied or moved around.

Comment: thank you! Just one question: why do we need to use std::cref? Can we use just &date? What is the difference between std::cref and reference?

Comment: `&date` is a pointer and that would not work unless your callable itself takes a pointer.  It is well-known that `std::bind` and its friends always copies or moves the argument and never take them by reference. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10503693/3966456) can explain better than me.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace `predicate` with `make_predicate` lambda, which returns another lambda, which implements the `condition` evaluation:

```cpp
auto condition = ParseCondition(is);
auto make_predicate = [condition](const Date& date, const string& event) {
    return [&condition, date](const string& event) { return condition->Evaluate(date, event); };
};
```

or wrap existing predicate object:

```cpp
auto predicate = ...;
auto make_predicate = [&predicate](const Date& date) {
    return [&predicate, date](const string& event) { return predicate(date, event); };
```

and use it in `remove_if` call:

```cpp
auto to_remove = std::remove_if(events.begin(),events.end(), make_predicate(date));
```

Please note that I tried to minimize copying of `condition`/`predicate` objects, so `make_predicate` generated lambda cannot outlive them, should be used as temporary.